# Yii1/Yii2: How to organize code in web application?

Tags: web-applications, yii, directory-structure, yii2, yii-modules

When should I use applications, when modules or when should I just use controllers? I'm not sure how to divide my code into these components and I don't know when to use what. Can anyone provide some strategies or best practices? Or which practices could be regarded as coding horror?

I assume that extensions are intended to be published or to get shared. So these type of items are not relevant to this question.

I know: *it depends*. But there might be some advises that do not depend that much on the application itself and can be given in general. Or there are advises like: if you application is kind of this then do that.

What would you think about when RBAC comes into play, RESTful APIs or AJAX-related stuff? Or other things.

Comment: This question includes 5 question at once. Please read the stackoverflow rules `How to ask a question`. Complete the Yii 1.1 Blog tutorial and ready about MVC-Pattern's. Maybe this will help ya.

Comment: Sorry for that. I just thought there could be some general strategies that could be condensed to some paragraphs and that would be also helpful to others. So that one can get a quick approach how to do things. This on level that fits to stackoverflow.

Comment: "How do things" totally depends to "What kind of software in which environment are you writing, etc., etc.". A lot of thinks came op to my mind while thinking about this. There is no "regular" answer.

Comment: It ALWAYS depends, of course. But at least it could be said something like 'use an application if... otherwise use a module' or 'put ajax-called actions into an seperate module/controller' or 'never put all into a single controller'. I assume some quite general advises are possible.

Answer (score 2):

The Yii2 Definitive Guide, "Application Structure" section provides application organization information:
 → http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-overview.html

Entry Scripts, Controllers, Models, Views, Modules, Filters, Widgets, Assets and Extensions are covered. "Best Practices" can also be found in several of the "Application Structure" subsections.

RBAC is covered in the Yii2 Guide security section. RESTful APIs has it's own Yii2 Guide  section.  Asynchronous JS could be placed in an Assets Bundle or registered from View with registerJs() or registerJsFile().
 → http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html

RBAC, RESTful APIs and Ajax generally fit within the Yii2 "Application Structure" organization.